# Entity Framework Query #1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I'm trying to figure out how to limit my child dataset to only include active records...

```
    // Here's what I have currently...
    m_BackLoggerEntities.Stories
     .Include("Sprints")
     .Include("Tasks")
     .Include("Efforts")
     .Include("Products")
     .First(s => s.StoryId == id);


    // Here's what I thought I could do...
    m_BackLoggerEntities.Stories
     .Include("Sprints")
     .Include("Tasks")
     .Include("Efforts")
     .Include("Products")
     .Where(s => s.Tasks.Active)
     .First(s => s.StoryId == id);


    // I also tried this...
    m_BackLoggerEntities.Stories
     .Include("Sprints")
     .Include("Tasks")
     .Include("Efforts")
     .Include("Products")
     .First(s => s.StoryId == id && s => s.Tasks.Active));
```

Obviously none of these are working.  I'm not sure how else to do this...

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an exception? Zero results? Too many results? ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Alex James Tip 37](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/10/13/tip-37-how-to-do-a-conditional-include.aspx). 
According to example in linked article, it can be done like this:

```
var query = from story in m_BackLoggerEntities.Stories
            where story.StoryId == id
            select new {
                          story,
                          Tasks = from task in story.Tasks
                                  where task.Active
                                  select task
                       };

var stories = query
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Select(x => x.Story);
```

Each Story inside of "stories" should have only active Tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
Model = m_BackLoggerEntities.Stories
    .Include("Sprints")
    .Include("Tasks")
    .Include("Efforts")
    .Include("Products")
    .SingleOrDefault(s => s.StoryId == id);
```

Then, in your view:

```
@foreach (var task in Model.Tasks.Where(t => t.Active))
```

Comment: This is a very old question....  "Oct 29 '09"  Thanks but I was trying to AVOID using the foreach.  How it was implemented was inconsequential to me.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to "simulate" what I want is to use...

```
        var storyToDetail =
            m_BackLoggerEntities.Stories
                .Include("Sprints")
                .Include("Tasks")
            .Include("Efforts")
            .Include("Products")
                .First(s => s.StoryId == id);
```

Then in the foreach in the view...

```
            <% foreach (var task in Model.Tasks.Where(t => t.Active))
```

But this of course brings back a lot more records then I want.